# External script not working in html file, please what am doing wrong

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have the below game.mjs file with the below code

```
import Player from './Player.mjs';
import Collectible from './Collectible.mjs';

const socket = io();
const canvas = document.getElementById('game-window');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const load = () => {
  context.fillStyle = "#000000";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillText("Coin Race", 100, 30);
  context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
  context.strokeRect(5, 35, canvas.width - 10, canvas.height - 40)
}

load();
```

I have the below in index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Secure Real-Time Multiplayer Game</title>
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="An example for the fCC InfoSec Secure Real-Time Multiplayer Game project"
    />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Secure Real Time Multiplayer Game</h1>
    </header>
    <hr style="margin: 25px" />
    <div class="container">
      <canvas 
        ref="game"
        id="game-window" 
        width="640" 
        height="480"
      >
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
 <script src="../public/game.mjs" type="module"></script>
</html>
```

Th external file isnt running using the script tag but if I add the code directly into the html file in the script tag it works.

Can someone please tell me what am doing wrong.

I notice that when I comment out the below in game.mjs, the external script runs

```
import Player from './Player.mjs';
import Collectible from './Collectible.mjs';

const socket = io();
```

Thank you

Comment: Any errors in the console in dev tools?

Comment: I sure hope u r using nodejs. So to add external scripts to your html, first u need to put external scripts in public folder, declare that folder as static, then use `server url + path to the file`

Comment: Hi @phuzi no errors in console

Comment: Hi @skmak all that is done but not working

Comment: Any errors in network tab - failed requests, not found etc.?

Comment: Hi @phuzi no error seen in network tab. App status shows "ok" in green

Comment: Hi @phuzi I edited my comment to add what I noticed. i.e. if I comment out the first 3 lines in game.mjs, the external script runs

Comment: It looks like there's probably an issue with your pathing, can you show us your server file?

Comment: I can see you r writing relative paths for script and css files. It simply won't work, you need to provide absolute path.

Comment: can you share your app.mjs file, mean the entry file for your application?

Answer (score 0):

Issue found. I changed app.listen in my server.js file to http.listen and its working fine now. Thank you for your time and assistance

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).